# Good TS fit but no stationarity

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, stationarity

I have yearly time-series that I want to predict, and for that I fitted an ARX (auto-regressive with a exogenous input) model to previous years (training set) and test it for the last year. My prediction is quite good. I have a very approximated shape and a good pearson ch2. My problem is that if I do an autocorrelation test with k-lags, I conclude that I do not have a stationary time-series. Does this means that my fit is not reliable?

Comment: Assuming you were using Ljung-Box test for autocorrelations in model residuals, why do you conclude that your series is nonstationary? You would normally conclude that your residuals are not autocorrelated or autocorrelated. If you wonder about nonstationarity, presumably a unit root, in your dependent variable, you could test that using, for example, an augmented Dickey-Fuller (ADF) test or KPSS test.

Comment: Ok, in that case I'm making some confusion. I thought that a lagged autocorrelation in a time-serie would mean nonstationary.

Comment: No, lagged autocorrelation in a time-series does not imply nonstationarity.